# Netbeans REST Client Automatically Opening URLs

Tags: browser, netbeans, hyperlink, rest-client

I'm having a problem in Apache NetBeans IDE 19 where I'm trying to open any link, and instead of my default browser (Tools->Options->General->Web Browser: Chrome), every link I open using left-click or Ctrl+left-click is opening in the REST client, and I cannot find the settings to change this. The REST Client I'm talking about can be found at Tools->REST Client

[image: Problem]

I have tried changing my default browser in the NetBeans settings, but unfortunately, it hasn't made any difference.

The only settings I found:

[image: REST Client]

Comment: Please remove the **UPDATE:** section of your question, and instead post an answer. Having the resolution to your problem appended to the question is unhelpful, and not the way things are done on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to contact the owner, and the owner is aware of the issue; I will mark this as answered once the bug is fixed.

See [Github](https://github.com/javierllorente/netbeans-rest-client/issues/9)